# gcc - Too few arguments to function 'select'

Tags: c

My goal is to convert an very old program from pre-ANSI/ISO C to modern C, but I ran into the following error, which I do not know how to solve it:

```
error: too few arguments to function ‘select’
```

Here are my header files for reference:

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/dir.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

And here is the affected part of the code:

```
int pmode(int aflag)
{
    register int **mp;

    flags = aflag;
    for (mp = &mp[0]; mp < &mp[sizeof(mp)/sizeof(mp[0])];)
        select(*mp++);
}
```

Comment: What is `select`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the `select` function does, but it's clear that you haven't provided all the required arguments

Comment: select in modern C does I/O multiplexing. an old C program may have used that name for some other purpose. Best to rename it.

Comment: Please show the complete error message -- most compilers will provide the visible declaration of `select` as part of the diagnostic.

Comment: Modern C does not use the `register` keyword.  It is noise.  The compiler ignores it; it knows better than you how to allocate registers. It does prevent you taking the address of the variable, but that's not a good reason to use it.

Comment: Did you check how your `select` function is declared?

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function, but an operator. -- And the resulting quotient is 1, as both operands are pointers. Are you sure that this is the correct source?

Comment: Is the source of this program publicly available?

Comment: Yes. It is from the UNIX/32V source code.

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX function (system call) [`select()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html)
has a much more complex interface than you're attempting to use:

> ```
> #include <sys/select.h>
>
> int select(int nfds, fd_set *restrict readfds,
>        fd_set *restrict writefds, fd_set *restrict errorfds,
>        struct timeval *restrict timeout);
> ```

It isn't entirely clear from the headers you list why the compiler is seeing a declaration for `select()`, but by far the safest thing to do is to rename the function in the code you're migrating to a new name.   Maybe, if your package has an acronym such as ABC, prefix the name with `abc_` to become `abc_select()`.